# Android navigation drawer max number of items

Tags: android, material-design, android-navigationview

What is the max limit for number of items for android navigation drawer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind Navigation Drawer is simple ListView and ArrayAdapter. You can set as many item as you can set in ListView.

As ArrayAdapter `size()` returns an int which means you can set maximum number as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: My question is w.r.t. UI guidlines. Is there any contraint on what should be the max number of items @Sharj

Comment: Design guideline doesn't say anything about numbers. Try not to put too many (keep less than 10). You can read more about it here https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

Comment: Just a small note: behind the official NavitagionView there is with the version 23.x.x a RecyclerView not a ListView. Before the 23.x.x there was a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 3):

[**Navigation drawer guidelines**](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns)

> When there is insufficient space to support tabs, side navigation is a good alternative. Side navigation can display many navigation targets at once. A drawer remains hidden until invoked by the user.

Technically you can use the [**NavigationView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html).
**Since it implements a RecyclerView there isn't a limit for the items** in the Navigation Drawer.

Usually the NavDrawer is a panel that displays the app’s main navigation options and it is the **higher components in the information hierarchy**.

Then it is a **good pratice to limit the number** of items to the top level functions of the app **to help the users in the navigation**.
Keep in mind the if the users need to scroll the navigation drawer to view all items, may be they will never use the hidden items.

If you need more info:

- [official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkT0vS14Um0)
- [offcial blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)